Fixed Tab with dnd-kit/sortable
Could you please help me implement the following code?
I need a fixed tab to always remain in its position and not shift left or right when other tabs are moved.
Essentially, it should work like this:
For example, if we have [1, 2, 3, 4] and tab 2 is fixed, then when dragging tab 3 to the position of tab 1, they should swap places without moving tab 2. The result should be [3, 2, 1, 4].
Additionally, when scrolling (horizontally, if the tabs do not fit on the screen of a mobile device), the fixed tab should stay in its place (not scroll horizontally).
Best regards.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import {
  DndContext,
  PointerSensor,
  closestCenter,
  useSensor,
} from '@dnd-kit/core';
import {
  arrayMove,
  horizontalListSortingStrategy,
  SortableContext,
  useSortable,
} from '@dnd-kit/sortable';
import { CSS } from '@dnd-kit/utilities';
import { Tabs } from 'antd';
const DraggableTabNode = ({ className, ...props }) => {
  const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, transition } =
    useSortable({
      id: props['data-node-key'],
    });
  const style = {
    ...props.style,
    transform: CSS.Translate.toString(transform),
    transition,
    cursor: 'move',
  };
  return React.cloneElement(props.children, {
    ref: setNodeRef,
    style,
    ...attributes,
    ...listeners,
  });
};
const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      key: '1',
      label: 'Tab 1',
      children: 'Content of Tab Pane 1',
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      label: 'Tab 2',
      children: 'Content of Tab Pane 2',
    },
    {
      key: '3',
      label: 'DISABLED',
      children: 'Content of Tab Pane 3',
    },
    {
      key: '4',
      label: 'Tab 4',
      children: 'Content of Tab Pane 4',
    },
    {
      key: '5',
      label: 'Tab 5',
      children: 'Content of Tab Pane 5',
    },
    {
      key: '6',
      label: 'Tab 6',
      children: 'Content of Tab Pane 5',
    },
    {
      key: '7',
      label: 'Tab 7',
      children: 'Content of Tab Pane 5',
    },
    {
      key: '8',
      label: 'Tab 8',
      children: 'Content of Tab Pane 5',
    },
  ]);
  const sensor = useSensor(PointerSensor, {
    activationConstraint: {
      distance: 10,
    },
  });
  const onDragEnd = ({ active, over }) => {
    if (active.id !== over?.id) {
      setItems((prev) => {
        const activeIndex = prev.findIndex((i) => i.key === active.id);
        const overIndex = prev.findIndex((i) => i.key === over?.id);
        return arrayMove(prev, activeIndex, overIndex);
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <Tabs
      items={items}
      renderTabBar={(tabBarProps, DefaultTabBar) => (
        <DndContext
          sensors={[sensor]}
          onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
          collisionDetection={closestCenter}
        >
          <SortableContext
            items={items.map((i) => i.key)}
            strategy={horizontalListSortingStrategy}
          >
            <DefaultTabBar {...tabBarProps}>
              {(node) =>
                node.key == '3' ? (
                  node
                ) : (
                  <DraggableTabNode {...node.props} key={node.key}>
                    {node}
                  </DraggableTabNode>
                )
              }
            </DefaultTabBar>
          </SortableContext>
        </DndContext>
      )}
    />
  );
};
export default App;


